# Проверка введенного слова

Tags: java

Меня интересует как можно проверить ввод данных. Мне нужно вводить слова но не более 5 символов все с маленькой буквы и английскими буквами.

```
Scanner scannerName = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = scannerName.next();
```

Я считываю строки а вот как в java сделать эту проверку не пойму.

Answer (score 3):

Освойте регулярные выражения. В данном случае выражение очень простое - от одного (вам же не нужно пустое имя?) до пяти символов из диапазона a..z.
[ideone code](https://ideone.com/GSfpZS)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner scannerName = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scannerName.next();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]{1,5}");  
        Matcher m = p.matcher(name);  
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(m.matches());

  asd12
  false

  asdeee
  false

  asd
  true

 цуке
 false
```

В данном случае, конечно, можно просто убедиться, что length в пределах 5 и циклом проверить каждый символ из нужного подмножества

```
   boolean res = (name.length() <= 5) && (name.length() > 0);
   if (res)
        for (int i=0;i<name.length();i++){
            char c = name.charAt(i);
            if (c < 'a' || c > 'z') {
                res = false;
                break;
            }
        }    
    System.out.println(name + " " +  res);
```

но для более сложных задач регулярные выражения окажут большую помощь.

Comment: Спасибо огромное все просто . Буду читать про регулярные выражения.

Comment: @user311256 Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)